# Python: Playing wav in memory using winsound - SND_MEMORY

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to play a wav file from memory rather than a file. This is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
>>> with open('my/file/dir/sound.wav','rb') as f:
>>>     data = f.read()
>>> data = base64.b64encode(data)
>>> data = data.decode('UTF-8')
```

So now data is a string object that represent bytes of an audio wav file.

```
>>> winsound.PlaySound(data,winsound.SND_MEMORY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Failed to play sound
```

Please help. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit:** Nevermind. [It's a bug.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3ggd9y/playing_a_wav_file_stored_in_memory_using_winsound/ctxywpr)

Comment: Use buffer on playing sound or use external player.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, why are you encoding data like that?
this is what i've done:

```
import winsound
memoryfile=open("myfilepath","rb")
winsound.PlaySound(memoryfile.read(), winsound.SND_MEMORY)
```

I've found that if you read the file before you tell winsound to play it it'll still play but will crash afterwards so don't do:

```
    memoryfile=open("myfilepath","rb").read()
```

also try using `\\` instead of `/` for directories

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, the problem lies in the following line:

```
>>> data = data.decode('UTF-8')
```

When you are encoding with `base64.b64encode()` you should decode with `base64.b64decode()`.

So, the code might be:

```
with open('my/file/dir/sound.wav','rb') as f:
    data = base64.b64encode(f.read())

winsound.PlaySound(base64.b64decode(data), winsound.SND_MEMORY)
```

I believe it solves the issue.

Comment: I do exactly same as you write but I have this error