# How can I play a .wav file in python 3.6?

Tags: wav, python-3.6, tkinter-canvas

Currently, I'm making a program using python 3.6, and I've been trying to make a sound effect occur after pressing a button. I found something from a different question asked, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921004/python-playing-wav-in-memory-using-winsound-snd-memory). Down below is my code.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, height=100, width=100, bg='blue')
c.pack()

with open('Users/lenonvo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python 3.6/Python 3 
Files/Python [3.6.3]/Sounds/Blook Game/Attack.wav','rb') as f:
    data = base64.b64encode(f.read())

def playSound():
    sound = winsound.PlaySound(base64.b64decode(data), winsound.SND_MEMORY)

def sound(event):
    global sound
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        playSound()
c.pack('<Key>', sound)
```

Then I got this error message:

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\lenonvo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Python 3 
Files\Python 3.6.3\Test2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenonvo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Python 3 
Files\Python 3.6.3\Test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open('Users/lenonvo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python 3.6/Python 
3 Files/Python [3.6.3]/Sounds/Blook Game/Attack.wav','rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'Users/lenonvo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python 3.6/Python 3 
Files/Python [3.6.3]/Sounds/Blook Game/Attack.wav'
```

Any suggestions?

Also, I am not an advanced python coder, so if your answer could be simplistic, it would be very much appreciated. =]

Now one problem is fixed, thanks to [Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner), but now this error message comes up:

```
    data = base64.b64decode(f.read())
NameError: name 'base64' is not defined
```

Comment: the file was not found. check if it exists. check if your open command has the correct path. check if you need to mask smth - f.e. spaces. is there a linebreak in your string?

Comment: I'm trying to access a .wav file from my computer. Not sure if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
with open('Users/lenonvo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python 3.6/Python 3  Files/Python [3.6.3]/Sounds/Blook Game/Attack.wav','rb') as f:
```

is a *relative* path to where your prog runs.

Use

```
with open('C:/Users/lenonvo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python 3.6/Python 3 Files/Python [3.6.3]/Sounds/Blook Game/Attack.wav','rb') as f:
          ^^^^
```

Comment: That helped, but now I got a new error message. I put it in my edited version of my question.

Comment: @Peter.k less profanity and more phrasing would enable me to understand your problem with my answer.